# Why changing a variable does not work same as changing a state in react js?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, jsx

```
export default function navbar(props) {
  const text = "DARK MODE ";
  function handelMode() {
  
    if (props.mode==='light') {
      props.setmode('dark');
      text ="DARK MODE ";
    } else {
      props.setmode('light');
      text ="LIGHT MODE ";
    }
    
  }


<li className="nav-item">
          <button type="button" onClick={handelMode} class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mx-3 my-1">{text}</button>
          </li>
```

- I AM TRYING TO CHANGE MY 'text' VARIABLE USED IN "li" ITEM .
- I CAN USE 'USE-STATE' FOR IT BUT WHY NORMAL IF-ELSE DOES-NOT CHANGE TEXT VARIABLE.
- NOTE: 'MODE' & 'SETMODE' ARE "USE-STATE" FUNCTIONS USED IN NAVBAR ITEM (NOT SHOWN IN CODE ) TO CHANGE DARK AND LIGHT MODE (WHICH IS GOING WELL) BUT 'TEXT' IN "LI" IS NOT GETTING CHANGED .

Comment: Since `text` is not a state variable, its change does not trigger re-rendering from React. You should use `useState` if you need to observe variable changes.

Comment: React works with render cycle, every time a state variable changes, a new set of varaibles are created and old ones are thrown out, so settting local varaibles wont done any thing, if you want to take a deeper dive on  how it works, check this [great blog post](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#each-render-has-its-own-event-handlers) by Dan,
Cheers